# Angular2 : Control that a pasted string correspond to a given pattern

Tags: angular

How can I control that a pasted string in an input corresponds to a given pattern :

```
<input type="text" (pasted)="myRegex.match($event)">
```

It doesn't work since `$event` is a Clipboard event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `paste` event to:

```
(paste)="onPaste($event)"
```

And in your component you could:

```
onPaste(e: any) {
  let content = myRegex.match(e);  // should return boolean

  if (!content) {
     this.myModel = '';  // We clear it if it doesn't match
  }
}
```

Your input should look like:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
```